# Show Windows 10 native clock widget programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi, widget, windows-10, system-clock

So I use a clock replacement program. The problem is it also hijack clicks on the clock. So whenever I click on the clock in the notification area, program's popup menu launch rather than the default windows clock widget.

I also tried AHK `ControlClick` on `TrayClockWClass`. I still didn't get original widget. Is there any way to launch the original widget programmatically? I use Windows 10 1607.

I am fine with RunDll, API, SendMessage or any other way whatsoever.

Comment: This is not a supported facility, here is a kludge that dispatches a click:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356309/windows-7-left-click-on-clock-popup

Comment: @AlexK. This example is not working at all. Beside from my understand, the only thing it does is click on the control (which also don't work)

Answer (score 0):

Somebody upvoted my question today. So maybe they are looking for the answer. I posted it on autohotkey.com forums back then, and I get the answer there.

https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=21274

```
ControlGet, hClock, Hwnd,, TrayClockWClass1, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd ; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70770-win7-taskbar-clock-toggle/
if (hClock) {
    VarSetCapacity(IID_IAccessible, 16), DllCall("ole32\CLSIDFromString", "WStr", "{618736e0-3c3d-11cf-810c-00aa00389b71}", "Ptr", &IID_IAccessible)
    if (DllCall("oleacc\AccessibleObjectFromWindow", "Ptr", hClock, "UInt", OBJID_CLIENT := 0xFFFFFFFC, "Ptr", &IID_IAccessible, "Ptr*", accTrayClock))
        return
    VarSetCapacity(variant, A_PtrSize == 8 ? 24 : 16, 0), NumPut(VT_I4 := 3, variant,, "UShort")
    if (A_PtrSize == 4) ; https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=111355#p111355
        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(accTrayClock+0)+25*A_PtrSize), "Ptr", accTrayClock, "Int64", NumGet(variant, 0, "Int64"), Int64, NumGet(variant, 8, "Int64")) ; IAccessible::DoDefaultAction
    else
        DllCall(NumGet(NumGet(accTrayClock+0)+25*A_PtrSize), "Ptr", accTrayClock, "Ptr", &variant) ; IAccessible::DoDefaultAction
    ObjRelease(accTrayClock)
}
```